# What adds up to the damage of a high crit weapon?

Tags: dnd-4e, weapons, critical-hit, bonus-type

I'm seeking for the swarm intelligence of this forum because I couldn't find rules for it:

I have a high crit weapon (scimitar) which is

1. magically enhanced (+1)

and for which I have

2. a weapon focus (+1).

What adds to the damage on a crit?

1. The maximized power damage, including the named attribute's bonus (+5), 
   i.e.: 8+5+1+1=15
2. The d6 for a crit with the specific magical weapon,
   i.e.: 15+d6

And here my problems start ...

3a. Do I roll a D8 for scimitar only?

OR

3b. Does the magical enhancement bonus add to that roll, too?

3c. Does the weapon focus add to that damage roll, too?

3d. Or are these two bonuses only included once per attack and that as part of the maximized power damage?

Thanks a lot for your opinions!

Inge Tietz

Answer (score 6):

#### High crit only adds the weapon dice.

From the PHB, p217 (*emphasis mine*):

> **High Crit:** A high crit weapon deals more damage when you score a critical hit with it. A critical hit deals maximum weapon damage and an *extra* 1[W] at 1st–10th levels, an *extra* 2[W] at 11th–20th levels, and an *extra* 3[W] at 21st–30th levels. This *extra* damage is *in addition to* any critical damage the weapon supplies if it is a magic weapon.

The scimitar's damage die, 1[W], is a d8, so from 1st to 10th level it adds 1d8 damage on a crit. High crit does not add a second damage *roll*, it adds *extra* damage to the normal damage roll.

Comment: Damage Rolls, p. 276:

"In addition, any of the following factors might apply to a damage roll:

✦ Racial or feat bonuses

✦ An enhancement bonus (usually from a magic weapon or an implement)

✦ An item bonus

✦ A power bonus

✦ Untyped bonuses"

------------------------------------------------------------

And on a high crit I ROLL the extra damage ...

Comment: @IngeTietz See edit. High crit is *itself* extra damage; it is not a second damage roll.